# How are SEF addresses implemented using Nuxt route?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm making a website with `Nuxt 3` and `Vue`. I need to have a page like this:

```
/articles/section
```

This page should call the file `/pages/articles.vue` with passing the value `section` as a parameter. I created a file, and in `nuxt.config.ts` added the following code:

```
router: {
  extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      path: '/articles/:section',
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/articles.vue')
    })
  }
}
```

But now when I go to the `/articles/section` page, `Nuxt` gives me a 404 error. What did I miss?

Comment: I would like to make a clarification on your question. So, you have an `articles` page and a dynamic `section` page, but, you get 404 error when visiting `/articles/section` right? May I ask the purpose of the codes included in your question?

Comment: @ReaganM I only have the file `/pages/articles.vue`, and I need the name of the section to be written not in the get parameter, but as a string, for a more beautiful link. In `articles.vue` should be a code that uses the dynamic code of the section and receives all the articles of a particular section from the server. There are many sections, and it will be inconvenient to generate a separate static page for each.

Comment: @ReaganM Yes, that's right. When I go to the `/articles` page, the contents of the `articles.vue` file are displayed. But when I go to the `/articles/my_section` page, `vue` outputs 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a better example that is related to what you are trying to achieve. So I created my own example and hopefully this will guide you to achieve your needs.

Change the codes on your `nuxt.config.ts` to this codes.

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    hooks: {
        'pages:extend'(pages) {
            pages.push({
                name: 'section',
                path: '/articles/:section',
                file: '~/pages/articles.vue'
            })
        }
    }
})
```

The content from the Article page will be the same on the dynamic section.

Here is the file structure of the pages.

```js
- pages
 - articles.vue
```

To see it in action, copy these codes and test it on your end.

`~/pages/articles.vue`

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const searchedArticle = ref<string | null>(null)

function onSearchArticle() {
    useRouter().push(`/articles/${searchedArticle.value}`)
}

</script>
<template>
    <main>
        <input
            type="text"
            v-model="searchedArticle"
            placeholder="Search Article"
        />
        <button @click.prevent="onSearchArticle">Search</button>
        <div class="go-back">
            <NuxtLink to="/articles">Back to Article's page</NuxtLink>
        </div>
        <div class="searched">
            <h2>Section article: {{ $route.params.section }}</h2>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css">
.searched {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.go-back {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
```

[image]

I hope this will give you an idea and this example won't throw 404 error when viewing the dynamic section.

Comment: I did it a little differently. Configuring routing in `nuxt.config` as you have, but then just in the file `/pages/articles.vue` I access the `$route.params.section` variable and get the desired section. I did not create an additional file `[section.vue]`.

Comment: Yeah, it should be okay since the `hooks` in the nuxt.config.ts will create `section` page. Maybe this link will be helpful for you as well
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/custom-routing#using-the-pagesextend-hook